# ACF / Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom Taxonomy called **downloads_categories** which works like categories and has a list of Models;

[image]

The taxonomy is linked to a custom post type called **downloads** the post type contains 2 elements/fields *(the_title)* and *(the_field('file'))*.

In my template taxonomy-downloads_categories.php how do I echo all the posts which are associated to the current taxonomy term? I currently use the following code and it only echo's the 1st available download.

```
<a href src="<?php the_field('file'); ?>" alt="" /><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Comment: You need a regular wordpress loop, just like any other page

Comment: Thank you @steve sometimes I need to take a step back and take a fresh look at the basics!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment, you need a regular wordpress loop:

```
<?php if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
    <a href src="<?php the_field('file'); ?>" alt="" /><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```